# Why does using an empty call hook_exit call create an error?

Tags: 7, hooks

I added the following code to MY_MODULE.

```
function MY_MODULE_exit() {
}
```

Since I did it, I get this error message:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function `answers_question_locked_p()` in MY_MODULE.module on line 178

The line happens to be within MY_MODULE_node_view(). Any thoughts on why this behavior occurs?

The code on line 177-179 is the following.

```
if ($view_mode == 'full') {
  if (answers_question_locked_p($node)) {
    $node->content['lock_message'] = array(
      // ...
    );

    // Omissis.
  }
}
```

This code does not cause errors when the empty `hook_exit()` is deleted and the cache cleared.

Comment: that depends on what is on line 178

Comment: You don't have a function named `answers_question_locked_p`, and if you do, drupal can't find it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I guess that's just what I don't yet understand. Why does what's on line 178 matter? The error does not happen w/o the call. What does inserting the empty call to hook_exit do that creates the error? Is hook_node_view now called in a different way or with drupal in a different bootstrap state?  (Note: I've edited the question to show what is on line 178.)

Comment: May you show the full code of the function containing those lines (177-179) and the function before that?